# Change navbar-toggle button icon when active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I`m uisng bootstrap 3, and I have a question. Is it possible to change navbar-toggle button icon when it is active, if yes, how?
Example:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just use appropriate css classes to change button image when it is activated.

Comment: Please present us with some code or jsfiddle , so that we cna help you in a better way .

Answer (score -1):

You need override Bootstrap style and need to add 2 icon's one will show by default and second will show when menu is active